# How to fit my background image to different screens?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to fit my background image to my different media queries but i cannot make the image to display completely.

```css
.main {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: url("images/BANNER.png");
  background-size: cover;
  position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

@media (max-width:375px) {
  .main {
    background-image: url("images/BANNER.png");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="main" id="main">
  <div class="content">
    <h2>Hello, this is <br><span>Aptos Koalas</span></h2>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/AptosKoalas" class="btn LFM">LFM!</a>
  </div>
</section>
```

I was able to center de image with background-position but i cannot make the image to show completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using the `background-size: cover;` property that will resize the background image to cover the entire container, even if it has to stretch the image or cut a little bit off one of the edges.

try with `background-size: contain`